# PHP json API client calls

Tags: php, json, curl

I need some help translating the following shell scripts calls to PHP

```
curl -3 --cookie /tmp/cookie --cookie-jar /tmp/cookie --insecure --data "login=login" --data "username=admin" --data "password=password" URL-HERE/login

curl -3 --cookie /tmp/cookie --cookie-jar /tmp/cookie --insecure --data "json={'cmd':'get-data', 'id':'1'}" URL-HERE/api
```

I'm having some difficulties with the first curl command.

Got as far as:

```
    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1 );
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER , 1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie");
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie");
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10000);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"URL-HERE/login");

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST ,1);
    $post = array(
      "username" => 'admin',
      "password" => 'password',
      "login" => 'login',
    );
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Which seems to always render the the login form from URL-HERE/login, and subsequent JSON requests using the above cookie seem to fail with error message "need to be logged in before attempting these requests". However, the two shell command above work flawlessly.

Am I correct in thinking --data parameters become post vars. and JSON data is a post field named "json" with contents that's been returned by `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: (I rewrote some of my code, NOT tested)

```
$url = 'URL-HERE/login';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$postfields = "login=login&username=$username&password=$password";

$cookie="/tmp/cookie";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: That worked. Provided i use the same cookie for subsequent API calls.